# Event delegation for specific target Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-template

How to implement event delegation for specific target in angular 2

Consider having the below html

```
<ul>
   <li><span>hello</span><button>button</button></li>
</ul>
```

And i want to implement event delegation to target the li even if the user clicked on the span or the button inside the li, the li event will run.

for example we can achieve this in jquery using :

```
$('ul').on('click', 'li', function() {
  console.log($(this)) // always log the li whenever you clicked inside it
})
```

my actual scenario in angular :

```
<div class="list-group" (click)="selectOption($event)">

<button type="button" class="list-group-item" *ngFor="let option of options; let i = index"
 [attr.data-value]="option.key" [attr.data-label]="option.displayColumnValue">
  <span [title]="option.displayColumnValue ">
   {{ option.displayColumnValue }} 
  <small *ngIf="option.email">({{ option.email }})</small>
  </span>

  <a *ngIf="option.group" class="drilldown" [attr.data-key]="option.key"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
</button>
```

Comment: sorry why don't wrap all your clikkable area INSIDE a div and then put a click event on it?

Comment: You can bind a function to the (click) event in the ul element, but this wont give you control over which element was clicked withouth extra logic

Comment: so there is no option in angular out of the box to achieve this, you have to handle it yourself.

Comment: I dont want to repeat the click event for each button.

Comment: what is it that you want to do specifically? could you explain some more about your use case?

Answer (score 2):

you can achive this by creating a directive with `@HostListner`

```
@Directive({selector: '[dele]')
export class delegator{
   @HostListener('click') clicked($event) {
      console.log($event.target); // this will be a child button
   }
}
```

Now call it like this

```
<ul dele>
   <li><span>hello</span><button>button</button></li>
</ul>
```

**EDIT**

if you want to add `hostlistner` to a specific element then use an event

```
@Directive({
   selector: "[dele]"
})
export class deleDirective {
   @Output() onFocusOut: EventEmitter<boolean> = new EventEmitter<false>();

   @HostListener("focusout", ["$event"])
   public onListenerTriggered(event: any): void {
       this.onFocusOut.emit(true);
   }
}
```

In the html add the directive as well as the

```
<ul>
       <li dele (onFocusOut)='clickFunction($event)'><span>hello</span><button>button</button></li>
 </ul>
```

Comment: i want to target the li not the button inside it

Comment: $('ul').on('click', 'li', function() {
  console.log($(this)) // this will always refer to the li whenever you clicked inside it
})

Comment: on my case i have multiple li so i don't want the event to be repeated lets say 1000 times, i guess there is nothing in angular to achieve this directly.

Comment: I solved it by getting the closest('li') from the targeted element
const listItemBtn = event.target.closest('.list-group-item');

Comment: yep that makes sense